# read contacts from phonebook and when clicking on the contact name show their phone numbers on a different page

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent

im new in app development so i wrote a code where i want to read my contacts list from phone book and have managed to click on that contact. now the problem is i want to display the contacts name and phone number on a different page when the contacts shown on my contacts listView is clicked. i want to show the name and phone number on the add_friend class.

this is the contact.java

```
public class Contact extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager
    .LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
private static final String[] FROM_COLUMNS = {
        ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID,
        Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB ?
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY :
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.Data.PHOTO_ID,
};
private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSION = 0;private ContactAdapter mContactAdapter;
private RecyclerView mContactRecyclerView;


private static final int LOADER_ID = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.contacts);



    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(Contact.this, Manifest.permission
            .READ_CONTACTS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                Contact.this,
                new String[]{
                        Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS
                },
                REQUEST_PERMISSION
        );
    } else {
        getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_ID, savedInstanceState, this);
    }

    //Initialising LoaderManger
    getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_ID, savedInstanceState, this);

    mContactRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_contacts);
    mContactRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mContactRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(Contact.this));

    mContactAdapter = new ContactAdapter(Contact.this, null, ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID);

    mContactRecyclerView.setAdapter(mContactAdapter);


}

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    switch (id) {
        case LOADER_ID:
            return new CursorLoader(Contact.this, ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, FROM_COLUMNS, null, null,
                    (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB ?
                            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY :
                            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME) + " ASC");
        default:
            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("no id handled");
            return null;
    }
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    mContactAdapter.swapCursor(data);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    mContactAdapter.swapCursor(null);
}
```

}

this is contactADAPTER

```
public class ContactAdapter extends CursorRecyclerViewAdapter<ContactAdapter.ContactViewHolder> {
public ContactAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor, String id){
    super(context, cursor, id);
}TextView contact_name;

@Override
public ContactViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_contact,
            parent, false);
    contact_name=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.contact_display_name);
    contact_name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent contIntent= new Intent(mContext.getApplicationContext(), Add_Friend.class );
            contIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK| Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
            mContext.getApplicationContext().startActivity(contIntent);
        }
    });
    return new ContactViewHolder(view);
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ContactViewHolder viewHolder, Cursor cursor) {
    //Now we can handle onBindViewHolder

    long contactId = getItemId(cursor.getPosition());

    //Setting the username
    String username = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(
            Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB ?
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY :
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
    ));

    viewHolder.contactDisplayNameTextView.setText(username);

    //Setting the photo

    long photoId = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(
            ContactsContract.Data.PHOTO_ID
    ));

    if (photoId != 0) {
        Uri contactUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                contactId);
        Uri photoUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(contactUri, ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo
                .CONTENT_DIRECTORY);

        viewHolder.contactDisplayImageView.setImageURI(photoUri);
    } else {
        viewHolder.contactDisplayImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.prof_icon);
    }
}

public static class ContactViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    ImageView contactDisplayImageView;
    TextView contactDisplayNameTextView;

    public ContactViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        contactDisplayImageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.contact_display);
        contactDisplayNameTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.contact_display_name);

    }
}
```

}

AND THIS IS THE RECYCLER VIEW

```
public abstract class CursorRecyclerViewAdapter<VH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder> extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VH> {
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private static final String TAG = CursorRecyclerViewAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

protected Context mContext;

private Cursor mCursor;
private boolean mDataValid;
private int mRowIdColumn;
private String mId;
private DataSetObserver mDataSetObserver;


public CursorRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor, String id) {
    mContext = context;
    mCursor = cursor;
    mDataValid = cursor != null;
    mRowIdColumn = mDataValid ? mCursor.getColumnIndex(id) :-1;
    mId = id;
    mDataSetObserver = new NotifyingDataSetObserver(this);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.registerDataSetObserver(mDataSetObserver);
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
protected Cursor getCursor() {
    return mCursor;
}


@Override
public VH onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(VH holder, int position) {
    if (!mDataValid) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("this should only be called when the cursor is valid");
    }
    if (!mCursor.moveToPosition(position)) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("couldn't move cursor to position " + position);
    }
    onBindViewHolder(holder, mCursor);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (mDataValid && mCursor != null) {
        return mCursor.getCount();
    }
    return 0;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    if (mDataValid && mCursor != null && mCursor.moveToPosition(position)) {
        return mCursor.getLong(mRowIdColumn);
    }
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void setHasStableIds(boolean hasStableIds) {
    super.setHasStableIds(true);
}

public abstract void onBindViewHolder(VH viewHolder, Cursor cursor);
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public void changeCursor(Cursor cursor) {
    Cursor old = swapCursor(cursor);
    if (old != null) {
        old.close();
    }
}

public Cursor swapCursor(Cursor newCursor) {
    if (newCursor == mCursor) {
        return null;
    }
    final Cursor oldCursor = mCursor;
    if (oldCursor != null && mDataSetObserver != null) {
        oldCursor.unregisterDataSetObserver(mDataSetObserver);
    }
    mCursor = newCursor;
    if (mCursor != null) {
        if (mDataSetObserver != null) {
            mCursor.registerDataSetObserver(mDataSetObserver);
        }
        mRowIdColumn = newCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(mId);
        mDataValid = true;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    } else {
        mRowIdColumn = -1;
        mDataValid = false;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        //There is no notifyDataSetInvalidated() method in RecyclerView.Adapter
    }
    return oldCursor;
}

public void setDataValid(boolean dataValid) {
    mDataValid = dataValid;
}

private class NotifyingDataSetObserver extends DataSetObserver {
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;

    public NotifyingDataSetObserver(RecyclerView.Adapter adapter) {
        this.adapter = adapter;
    }

    @Override
    public void onChanged() {
        super.onChanged();
        ((CursorRecyclerViewAdapter) adapter).setDataValid(true);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onInvalidated() {
        super.onInvalidated();
        ((CursorRecyclerViewAdapter) adapter).setDataValid(false);
    }
}
```

this is where i want to show the name and number of the contact selected

public class Add_Friend extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add__friend);
}
```

}

this is the layout where I want the name and phone number to appear

```
              ' <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xml :android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:gravity="center_vertical"
          android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
          android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
          android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
          android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/contact_display_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="Contact Username"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/contact_display"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/number"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="0986857456"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/contact_display_name"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/contact_display_name"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/contact_display_name"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add friend"
        android:layout_below="@+id/contact_display_name"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/contact_display"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:src="@drawable/prof_icon"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

this is how I want it to appear
[this is how I want it to appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92r51.png)

Comment: Send data through Intent to the activity,  inten.putextra or something i don't exactly recall method name.

Comment: i don't follow lvl4fi8

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent contIntent= new Intent(mContext.getApplicationContext(), Add_Friend.class );
```

after this line put your data like this :

```
contIntent.putExtra("name", data1);
contIntent.putExtra("number", data2);
```

and get data in `onCreate` from `Add_Friend` activity like this:

```
String name = getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
    String number = getIntent().getStringExtra("number");
```

Comment: @MalusiGcabashe I'm using this method and works fine. maybe you can put some logs for data befor and after getting data to check what is wrong